# Sync nested subscribes in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular5

I've a function like:

```js
function(param: any): Subject<any> {

    let newsubj: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    let thing;

    this.dataContextService.dataContext.getFullThing({ param: param }).subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {

            thing = result.thing;

            this.dataContextService.dataContext.Table.Query(query => query
                .orderBy(["ID desc"])
                .top(1)
            ).subscribe(number => {
                if (number) {

                    let increment = number + 1;

                    let newObject = new Object({ id: increment, thing: thing });
                    this.dataContextService.dataContext.Favorite.Post(newObject).subscribe(result => {
                        newsubj.next(newObject);
                        newsubj.complete();
                    })

                }

            })
        }

    })
    return newsubj;
}
```

I can't get to sync the execution of this http calls with rxjs, can please someone help?
(rxjs newbie here). Thanks

Comment: dont nest subscribers

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to use `forkJoin`. It works similar to `Promise.all([...])` but in `Observable` field. Modify your code in the following way:

```
forkJoin(
        this.dataContextService.dataContext.getFullThing({ param: param }),
        this.dataContextService.dataContext.Table.Query(query => query
            .orderBy(["ID desc"])
            .top(1)
        )
    ).subscribe(
        ([fullThing, number]) => {
            thing = fullThing && fullThing.thing;

            if (number) {
                let increment = number + 1;

                let newObject = new Object({ id: increment, thing: thing });
                this.dataContextService.dataContext.Favorite.Post(newObject).subscribe(result => {
                    newsubj.next(newObject);
                    newsubj.complete();
                });
            }
        }
    );
```

UPD: As suggested in comments, it's better to use `forkJoin` rather than `ForkJoinObservable` so I edited my answer to reflect this. You can also see more examples of `forkJoin` use here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: I would suggest that the `forkJoin` factory function should be used instead. Classes like `ForkJoinObservable` were an implementation detail and they've been [removed in RxJS v6](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.0.0-rc.0/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts).

Comment: dont nest subscriptions

Comment: @Jota.Toledo subscription inside, depends on the data that comes from the backend. as I see from the original code, in case of number === null or undefined it shouldn't be called at all.

Comment: so? that doesnt mean that you r obligated to nest subscriptions

Comment: @Jota.Toledo please suggest another variant as an answer. I'd be more than happy to look on it and if it will be better, I'll even remove mine completely.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I'm just consuming a closed OData services implementation generated from Entity Framework controllers, so I don't have liberty to change the Observables.

Comment: @cartant tnks for the help,  I will try this solution.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh tnks for the help, I will try this solution.